# как переключить локаль программно?

Tags: flutter, dart

Как переключить локаль программно? При нажатии на кнопки, локаль должна меняться, но она не меняется. Далее, полный код и скриншот.

***intl_en.arb***

```
{
 "str1" : "Name Page",
 "str2" : "english",
 "str3" : "russian",
 "str4" : "Hello World!"
}
```

***intl_ru.arb***

```
{
 "str1" : "Имя Страницы",
 "str2" : "английский",
 "str3" : "русский",
 "str4" : "Привет Мир!"
}
```

***main.dart***

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_localizations/flutter_localizations.dart';
import 'generated/l10n.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

Locale _locale = const Locale('en', '');

void funEn() {
 _locale = const Locale('en', '');
}

void funRu() {
 _locale = const Locale('ru', '');
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {

 const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return MaterialApp(

   localizationsDelegates: const [
    S.delegate,
    GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
    GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
    GlobalCupertinoLocalizations.delegate,
   ],

   supportedLocales: const [
    Locale('en', ''), //English
    Locale('ru', ''), //Russian
   ],

   //установка локали для приложения
   locale: _locale,

   debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
   title: 'Name App',
   theme: ThemeData(
    primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
   ),
   home: const MyHomePage(),
  );
 }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
 const MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

 @override
 _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

 @override
 void initState() {
  super.initState();
 }

 @override
 void dispose() {
  super.dispose();
 }

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
   appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text(S.of(context).str1),
   ),
   body: SafeArea(
    child: Column(
     mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
     children: [

      Padding(
       padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16.0),
       child: Row(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
        children: [
         TextButton(
          onPressed: () {
           setState(() {
            funEn();
           });
          },
          child: Text(S.of(context).str2),
          style: ButtonStyle(
           alignment: Alignment.center,
           minimumSize: MaterialStateProperty.all(const Size(128, 36)),
           foregroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.deepPurple),
           backgroundColor:  MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.grey.shade200),
           padding: MaterialStateProperty.all(EdgeInsets.zero),
           textStyle: MaterialStateProperty.all(const TextStyle(fontSize: 20)),
           side: MaterialStateProperty.all(
            const BorderSide(
             color: Colors.red,
             width: 1.0
            )
           ),
           shape: MaterialStateProperty.all(
            const RoundedRectangleBorder(
             borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5.0)),
            )
           ),
          ),
         ),
         TextButton(
          onPressed: () {
           setState(() {
            funRu();
           });
          },
          child: Text(S.of(context).str3),
          style: ButtonStyle(
           alignment: Alignment.center,
           minimumSize: MaterialStateProperty.all(const Size(128, 36)),
           foregroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.deepPurple),
           backgroundColor:  MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.grey.shade200),
           padding: MaterialStateProperty.all(EdgeInsets.zero),
           textStyle: MaterialStateProperty.all(const TextStyle(fontSize: 20)),
           side: MaterialStateProperty.all(
            const BorderSide(
             color: Colors.red,
             width: 1.0
            )
           ),
           shape: MaterialStateProperty.all(
            const RoundedRectangleBorder(
             borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5.0)),
            )
           ),
          ),
         ),
        ]
       ),
      ),

      Expanded(
       flex: 1,
       child: Center(
        child: Text(
         S.of(context).str4,
         style: const TextStyle(
          fontSize: 36.0,
          color: Colors.pink
         ),
        ),
       ),
      ),

     ]
    ),
   ),
  );
 }

}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Вы вызываете setState не там.

Вот пример, как можно сделать:

```dart
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();

  static void ofLocale(BuildContext context, Locale locale) => context.findAncestorStateOfType<_MyAppState>().setLocale(locale);
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  Locale _locale;

  void setLocale(Locale value) {
    setState(() {
      _locale = value;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      locale: _locale,
      localizationsDelegates: const [
        S.delegate,
        GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
        GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
        GlobalCupertinoLocalizations.delegate,
      ],
      supportedLocales: const [
        Locale('en', ''), //English
        Locale('ru', ''), //Russian
      ],
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Name App',
      theme: ThemeData(
       primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

...

MyApp.ofLocale(context, Locale('en', ''));
```